# Работа с файлами и строками в Delphi 7

Tags: файлы, строки, delphi-7

у меня есть файл

```
"Client": {
    "Version": {
        "FirstRun": "false",
        "Release"{
            "LastBuildVersion": "9093564",
            "LastSeenPatchNotesVersion": "9093523"
        }
    },
    "Voice": {
        "InputDevice": "Микрофон (Realtek High Definition Audio)",
        "OutputDevice": "Динамики (Realtek High Definition Audio)",
        "OutputVolume": "60",
        "TransmissionKeys": "5645646851"
    },
```

Из него мне нужно вынуть строку

> "TransmissionKeys": "5645646851"

название файла `BELASH.txt`
 как мне это правильно реализовать в Delphi 7 на языке паскаль ?

Comment: Блин, ну сделайте класс того что у вас есть и потом парсите этот текст как json со структурой которую вы составите

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy крайне сильно не понял вас, так как начал изучать эту программу совсем недавно

Comment: а, ну ладно, сори, щяс

Comment: Есть два решения твоей задачи : Крутой и не очень (про него писать не буду так как он очень убогий и через регулярные выражения). Крутой вариант : то-что ты скинул похоже на json структуру, то-есть её можно распарсить и получить объект с которым удобно работать, крч советую почитать --> http://www.webdelphi.ru/2011/10/rabota-s-json-v-delphi-2010-xe2/ и http://digital-flame.ru/2016/02/29/delphi-json-obektyi-prostyie-primeryi/ . Кстати если ты новичок и собираешься реально подняться в будущем, советую тебе разобраться и почитать что такое json, потом очень часто будет встречаться.

Comment: И ещё Delphi 7, это среда разработки, а то "программа" звучит слишком обобщенно :)